# Preventing or Limiting Spammers/Bad Guys from Using My Domain

Tags: domain-name-system, email, domain-name

I started getting replies in my catch all email box that spam and viruses has been sent from my domain. Someone is spoofing my email addresses to send out spam and malware. I was wondering if anything can be done to limit/prevent this and also to make sure that legitimate emails from my domain doesn't get blacklisted? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your domain won't get blacklisted.  Most blacklisting is done by IP address, because it's normal for spammers to use other people's domains.

There isn't much you can do about it besides ensuring you have SPF and possibly DKIM setup for your domain.  Neither of these will prevent people from faking your email address, but they will help other servers make them as spam, so they never get delivered.